# getjson query is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Json page is : http://freegeoip.net/json/59.92.78.49

and my code is

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
       </script>
       <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
          $.getJSON("http://localhost/02/t.php",function(result){
                     alert(result.ip);
             });            
             });
           });
         </script>
```

this simple code is not working :(

Comment: How is is "not working"?  What do you see in your console?  Any errors?  Is this page also running on `http://localhost`?  Does `t.php` echo a valid JSON file?

Comment: You can provide a callback to that service for JSONP. Add `?callback=jsonp` to the end of the URL.

Comment: @Andy: In jQuery, you'd want to do `?callback=?`.  It will replace the `?` for you.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that in [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem like **[freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net/)** support `jsonp`,you can do:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://freegeoip.net/json/59.92.78.49",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.ip); // server response
        }
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3f5w7/)**